# Matlab - computing statistics (max, min, mean, median, std ...) at once

Tags: matlab, statistics

I believe that therre is a simple answer but I have not found it. I want to compute statistics for an array (max, min, mean, median, std) in other way than:

```
max = max(array)
min = min(array)
mean = mean(array)
median = median(array)
std = std(array
```

because (as I believe) it would go through the array every single time at least once. I am hoping that there is some function like

```
[max, min, mean, median, std,...] = stat(array)
```

similar to the R function

```
summary(Array) #R code
```

or to the stata command

```
des //stata
```

What function should I use in matlab?

Comment: If you have the Curve Fitting Toolbox, you can use [`datastats`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/curvefit/datastats.html). **Edit**: it turns out that it executes the max, min, etc functions itself internally.

Comment: still, at least it is in one function and it may be changed in future to run at once (so for code style I will use it if I don't find a way how to find the stats at once )

Comment: Or you could write your own function, which calls `min`, `max`, etc... in turn under the hood. This way you only have to call one function.

Comment: Well, I would have to use loops which would be probably slower than the internal looping in max or min. I would have to call min and max (so it would loop twice) but min and max can be computed both in one loop over the data).

Comment: @Pter is speed really that critical that call these 5 basic functions in serial is an issue for you? Or are you falling for the trap of trying to optimize something that doesn't need to be optimized? I'd say just wrap those five functions in your own `stat` function and call them one by one. They're so simple it's likely going to be fast enough...

Comment: @Dan no, I am actually pretty sure that the functions would be ok (or even if I used loops) because it is just for small data for a school assignement. But my goal is not just complete the assignement but to learn something or find clever ways how to do stuff. And I often work with bigger data where the speed could be an issue (not a big one but just waiting 10s instead of 2s since those functions are O(n)). I have thought that this is a thing that would be done very often so there would be a function for this. And it would not be hard to write one looping function to compute  the statistics.

Comment: @Pter I highly doubt you'll ever wait 2 seconds on those 5 functions, I think it's more likely to be around 0.000001 second vs 0.000005 seconds. Which is why I say that optimisation in this specific case is likely to waste more time than the total time saved by running the optimized code.

Comment: @Dan You're probably right. I can imagine use for such function if you have too much data that are not in memory and you have to stream them, so the fewer passes through the data the better. I was not asking because it would be a bottleneck but because I thought that there would be a simple way to achieve this. And I am well aware of the danger of premature optimization (and I know that this is the case but my goal was to learn something new)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that does it:

```
function [maxout, minout, meanout, medianout, stdout] = summary(array)

maxout    = max(array);
minout    = min(array);
meanout   = mean(array);
medianout = median(array);
stdout    = std(array);
```

Just copy that, save it to a file on your path called `summary.m`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a function than only loops though the vector once internally...

Comment: thanks for the answer :) But as Dan said I am asking for function that computes all that so it does not unnecessary loops - that is for example min and max do one loop through the data each but if I had function minmax that goes through the data and remember min and max, it can check the element of the array for both being maximum and minimum.